# Is there a faster way for filtering in datatable?

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a datatable that contains 2.5M rows. I would like to filter some rows in the datatable.

**Columns of the datatable :**

```
[IntCode] long
[BDIntCode] long
[TxnDT] DateTime
[TxnQuantity] decimal
[RecordUser] long
[RecordDT] DateTime
```

**My code is like below :**

```
            foreach (var down in breakDowns)
            {
                sw.Start();
                var relatedBreakDowns = firstGroup.Where(x => x.RelatedBDIntCode == down.ProcessingRowIntCode).ToList();
                if (relatedBreakDowns.Count == 0) continue;

                var filters = string.Format("BDIntCode IN ({0})", string.Join(",", relatedBreakDowns.Select(x => x.BDIntCode)));
                var filteredDatatable = datatable.Select(filters, "BDIntCode");
                foreach (var dataRow in filteredDatatable)
                {
                    var r = dataTableSchema.NewRow();
                    r["RecordUser"] = recordUser;
                    r["RecordDT"] = DateTime.Now;
                    r["TxnQuantity"] = dataRow["TxnQuantity"];
                    r["TxnDT"] = dataRow["TxnDT"];
                    r["BDIntCode"] = down.ProcessingRowIntCode;
                    dataTableSchema.Rows.Add(r);
                }
                sw.Stop();
                count++;
                Console.WriteLine("Group: " + unrelatedBreakDownGroup.RelatedBDGroupIntCode + ", Count : " + count + ", ElapsedTime : ms = " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + ", sec = " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000f );
                sw.Reset();
            }
```

The count of the breakDowns list is 1805, the count of the firstGroup list is 9880.

Comment: First question: why do you have that in a `DataTable`?

Comment: I have read your answer. I have used framework returns a datatable. But I can change it.

Comment: to be fair, most of my answer would work just fine from a `DataTable` - it is just less convenient, and has a few unnecessary overheads. That isn't the biggest problem.

Comment: I need to cast the datatable to a generic list for using a way like in your answer. This can take a bit extra time. Am I mistaken ?

Comment: for most of it, you can continue to work directly from `DataTable`, as long as you don't mind a whole lot of `.AsEnumerable`, `.Select<int>` etc

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would start by having that in a `List<SomeType>`, not a data-table. Then I would index the data: in your case, you are searching by `RelatedBDIntCode` and expecting multiple matches, so:

```
var index = firstGroup.ToLookup(x => x.RelatedBDIntCode);
foreach (var down in breakDowns) {
    var matches = index[down.ProcessingRowIntCode].ToList();
    //...
}
```

This avoids doing a complete scan of `firstGroup` for every item in `breakDowns`.

The next `IN` could be moved to a similarly indexed search, this time presumably on `BDIntCode`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to elaborate on Marc's answer - you should try and reduce the number of iterations that your code is performing.

The way your code is currently written, you are iterating over the breakdowns collection 1805 times and then for each of these iterations, you are iterating over the firstGroup collection 9880 times, so a total of 17833400 iterations without accounting for the datatable filter.

So, your approach should be to try and index the data up front, so as to reduce the number of iterations that are performed.

So step one could be to create an indexed mapping of `RelatedBDIntCode` to the correct rows of `datatable` into a Dictionary. Then you could loop over `breakDowns` and pull out the mapped rows for each `down` like this:

```
var dtIndexed = 
    firstGroup
    .GroupBy(x => x.RelatedBDIntCode)
    .ToDictionary
    (
        x => x.Key, //the RelatedBDIntCode you'll be selecting with 
        x =>        //the mapped rows. This is the same method of filtering, but you could try others
        {
            var filters = string.Format("BDIntCode IN ({0})", string.Join(",", x.Select(y => y.BDIntCode)));
            return datatable.Select(filters, "BDIntCode");
        }    
    );

foreach (var down in breakDowns)
{
    if(!dtIndexed.ContainsKey(down.ProcessingRowIntCode)) continue;

    var rows = dtIndexed[down.ProcessingRowIntCode];

    foreach (var row in rows)
    {
        var r = dataTableSchema.NewRow();
        r["RecordUser"] = recordUser;
        r["RecordDT"] = DateTime.Now;
        r["TxnQuantity"] = row["TxnQuantity"];
        r["TxnDT"] = row["TxnDT"];
        r["BDIntCode"] = down.ProcessingRowIntCode;
        dataTableSchema.Rows.Add(r);
    }
}
```

This approach should reduce the number of iterations your code is performing and thus improve performance.

Note in the code above, I have used exactly the same method of performing the filtering on the datatable - ie `datatable.Select(filter, order)`. You could experiment with trying to use `datatable.AsEnumerable().Where(row => ...)` as well